# Accessing the value in a dictionary that is inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I am reading a CSV file with Python 3/Pandas and I am struggling to access the values of a dictionary that is inside a list.

The picture below explains the problem better. I would like to access the name of the genre (e.g. Animation in the example).

If I try to do movies['genre'][0], it returns only the first row.

Thank you!

[image: pycode]

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] *in the question itself as formatted text*. But for starters, why use `pandas` here at all? It is certainly not good at working with list-of-dict's as elements.

Comment: I am reading a big CSV file that I want to filter and clean. That is why I want to extract the genre and then save the information to a new CSV file.

Comment: Your csv has strings that reperesent python `list`/`dict` literals? You've chosen the wrong serialization method. In any event, **that did not provide a [mcve]**. Please provide a [mcve]. Are you sure you actually have `list` objects in there? Or are they `str` objects? Again, **why pandas**? Pandas is for working with tabular data. It looks like you may potentially be able to massage your data to work well with pandas, but as it stands, it doesn't make much sense to use pandas. Good advice *and questions asking for debugging help generally* require a [mcve].

Comment: This is the data I am trying to read - https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata#tmdb_5000_movies.csv

Comment: Ok, that isn't a [mcve]. I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: Because *that isn't a [mcve]*. You should follow the guidelines for posting questions, check out [help] and [ask]. The question needs to be self-contained. Data should be provided as *text in the question*, not as a link to an external website. The same goes for *code* and example outputs (i.e. do not post images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the names in `movies['genres']`:

```
movies.genres.apply(pd.Series).melt().value.apply(pd.Series).name
```

With the first `apply` you'll turn the list of dicts into columns. Then `melt` them to unpivot them and then `apply(pd.series)` again to turn the dicts into columns.

Maybe you should use `pd.read_csv("file.csv", squeeze=True)` in order to get a Series instead of a Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
for gener in movies['genres']:
    print(gener)
    for entry in gener:
        print(entry)
```